# How to count votes for qualitative survey answers

Tags: survey, search-suggestion

We are creating a website for a client that wants a website based around a survey of peoples' '10 favourite things'.  There are 10 questions that each user must answer, e.g. 'What is your favourite colour', 'Who is your favourite celebrity', etc., and then the results are collated into a global Top 10 list on the home page.

The conundrum lies in both allowing the user to input anything they want, e.g. their favourite holiday destination might be 'Grandma's house', and being able to accurately count the votes accurately, e.g. User A might say their favourite celebrity is 'The Queen' and User B might says it's 'Queen of England' - we need those two answers to be counted as two votes for the same 'thing'.

If we force the user to choose from a large but predetermined list for each question, it restricts users' ability to define literally anything as their 'favourite thing'.  Whereas, if we have a plain text input field and try to interpret answers after they have been submitted, it's going to be much more difficult to count votes where there are variations in names or spelling for the same answer.

Is it possible to automatically moderate their answers in real-time through some form of search phrase suggestion engine?  How can we make sure that, if a plain text field is the input method, we make allowances for variations in spelling?

If anyone has any ideas as to possible solutions to this functionality, perhaps a piece of software, a plugin, an API, anything, then please do let us know.

Thank you and please just ask for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *automate* counting "The Queen" and "The Queen of England", you're in for work that might be more complex than it's worth for a "fun little survey".  If the volume is light enough, consider just manually counting the results.  Just to give you a feeling, what if someone enters "The Queen of Sweden" or "Queen Letifah Concerts"?

If you really want to go down that route, look into Natural Language Processing (NLP).  Specifically, the field of categorization.

For a general introduction to NLP, I recommend the relevant Wikipedia article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing

[RapidMiner](http://rapid-i.com/content/view/181/190/) is an open source NLP solution that would be worth looking into.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about the importance of how I worded that.  Although it is supposed to be a fun survey, it is a crucial feature of the website.  The website will not be a particularly low-traffic site either, though I can't say at the moment how many uniques we're talking about.

Comment: NLP is hard if you have no background in it (quite a learning curve).  You can consider automatically classifying results that are a really good match just using a string match (after all, lots of people will likely just type in Disney Land) and flagging the ones you can't string match for manual review.

Comment: I am sure there there will need to be some human intervention, but if we can get most of the heavy lifting done that would be ideal. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric J said, this is getting into cutting edge NLP applications. These are fields of study that are very important for AI/automation researchers and computer science in general, but are still very fledgeling. There are a number of programs and algorithms you can use, the drawbacks and benefits of which very widely. RapidMiner is good, WordNet is widely used in medical applications and should be relatively easy to adjust to your own corpus, and there are more advanced methods like latent Dirichlet allocation. Here are a few resources you should start with (in addition to the Wikipedia article provided above)

http://www.semanticsearchart.com/index.html

http://www.mitpressjournals.org/loi/coli

http://marimba.d.umn.edu/ (try the SenseClusters calculator)

http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Comment: Well, what if we just said to the system, 'scan the answers for their key words and phrases and then sort the results by frequency'. A bit like a tag cloud will increase font size in proportion to how often the word or phrase has been mentioned.  To be honest, I don't think the client has a large enough budget for us to consider going down the NLP route unless it's a very simple application of it.

Answer (score 0):

The best to classify short answers is `k-means clustering`. You need to apply stemming. Then you need to convert words into indexes using elementary dictionary. You can use `EverGroingDictionary.cs` from `sematicsearchart.com`. After throwing phrase to a dictionary it will be converted to sequence of numbers or vector. Introduce measure of proximity as number of coincidences in words and apply `k-means`, which is lightning fast `algorithm`. `k-means` will organize all answers into groups. Most frequent words in each group will be a signature of the group. Your whole program in `C++` or `C#` or `Java` must be less than 1000 lines.